# Can't connect to mongoDB: Mongo error { Error: querySrv ENODATA

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

My set-up consists of Node.js on Express on the back-end connected to mongoDB through mongoose. When I start the server, I get this error:

```
Mongo error { Error: querySrv ENODATA `database_hostname`
    at errnoException (dns.js:55:10)
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:243:19)
  code: 'ENODATA',
  errno: 'ENODATA',
  syscall: 'querySrv',
  hostname: `database_hostname` }
```

This results in me not being able to run my application on localhost due to it being constantly loaded.

At the same time connecting using MongoDB Compass works fine.

The database used to be working fine, but after I changed the location where I have been using it and created manually a new collection in Compass, which did not have a set-up locally, I started getting this error.

**Cluster configuration:**
SRV Record: off
Read Preference: Primary
SSL: System CA / Atlas Deployment
SSH Tunnel: None